# Send emails using cdo.mesage

Tags: cdo.message

**"The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 550 5.7.1 Initial access check failure**"

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check if the problem is related to UFT or whether it happens when using plain VBScript

Comment: It should not be a problem with either UFT or vbscript as the same code is working on another Citrix box. I assume it can be a firewall issue but again I am not sure about this as I am able to send email using "Outlook.Application" object on the same Citrix box.

Comment: I'm sure the problem isn't in the VBScript itself. But if you can rule out UFT effecting the problem you should probably remove the [tag:qtp] and [tag:hp-uft] tags and thus reach a wider audience.

Comment: Yeah.. Removed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. To use CDO message object we need the infrastructure admin to register the DG (or email from where the email needs to be sent) with the server IP. It will authenticate you to send emails using cdo message only on that particular server IP.

Hope it help anyone facing similar issue.